# post-receive hook not invoked when pushing changes to remote git repository

Tags: git, open-source, puppet, githooks, r10k

I am trying to automate the r10k deployment using git hooks. I am making changes on local system and pushing to remote git repository. I want that r10k should auto deploy once the changes are pushed . So i wrote the post-receive hook on puppet master which has following script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Deploying r10k new changes received"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/bin/r10k depoly environment -pv debug
```

I made that hook executable but still its not getting invoked when i push from my local machine.

Below is my r10k config file:

```
---
:cachedir: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/r10k
:sources:
  puppet:
    basedir: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments
    remote: https://github.com/Sanket-Shirode/puppet-control.git
```

Comment: post-receive hooks are server-side.. i doubt `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/bin/r10k` can be ran on github.com

Comment: Even that echo from hook is not working.
Server-side means the machine on which repository is cloned right?

Comment: what are the other options available for continuous integration??

Comment: Got it how the hook works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the hooks to work i had to create my own git server.